# use NSLayoutConstraint programmatically, not working as my expect

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I just want _view2 constraint it's top to _view1's bottom, and gap would be 100 for good. here is my codes:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    _view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    _view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_view1];

    _view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 100)];
    _view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    _view2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:_view2];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_view2
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:_view1
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                         multiplier:1 constant:100]];
}
```

it turns out to be like this:
[image]

but what I expect is like this:
[image]

Comment: Add more constraints for x position, width, and height

Answer (score 0):

according to @borrrden's suggestion, I just solved my problem

just add two more constraint on width and height, that will make sense.

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_view2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:_view1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                     multiplier:1 constant:0]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_view2
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:_view1
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                     multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```